# How to override style of Material-UI hidden component?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I've the following tabs example from Material-UI:

https://codesandbox.io/s/dark-rain-0ft9o

I'm trying to override this `<div class="MuiBox-root ...">` class, that imposes a `padding: 24px`.

[image: Material-UI Tabs Vertical]

But so far I could not do it because that Box component it's not declared on the code:

```js
 <TabPanel value={value} index={0}>
   Item One
 </TabPanel>
```

This box appears to be placed inside TabPanel component, but I can not override this box styles because it's not there:

How can I override it to impose `padding-top: 0px`?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's the relevant code from your sandbox:

```
function TabPanel(props) {
  const { children, value, index, ...other } = props;

  return (
    <Typography
      component="div"
      role="tabpanel"
      hidden={value !== index}
      id={`vertical-tabpanel-${index}`}
      aria-labelledby={`vertical-tab-${index}`}
      {...other}
    >
      {value === index && <Box p={3}>{children}</Box>}
    </Typography>
  );
}
```

The `Box` is inside the `Typography` within the `TabPanel` (`<Box p={3}>{children}</Box>`). `p={3}` means padding of 3 spacing units which are 8px each. You can change this `Box` as needed.

Comment: Omg! You saved me! I've been trying for hours to change the padding and now it seems that it's about the p={3}. Thank you soooo much!